# Debian adding user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, debian

I want to add a new user to my debian server.

The user should have access rights to ruby / rails / rvm / gem / git / and folder `/var/www/`

How do I add this user correctly?

The user should be able start a `webrick` server and install gems.

Comment: What have you searched for and tried so far and where are you stuck?  This is a pretty broad question and there are already a lot of resources on the Internet.

Comment: I've done a normal addusr ... can login and do most of thinks I want ... but I can install gems ... gem install <<gemname>> permision denied ... 

Can you tell me how I should add a user correctly?

Comment: why is this question downvoted so badly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard user should be able to do all that with a single-user installation of `rvm`.

Just follow the instructions on https://rvm.io

In order to check if your user has rights on `/var/www` :

check your user's groups :

```
groups #{username}
```

check permissions on /var/www :

```
ls -al /var | grep www
```

you should get something like :

```
drwxr-xr-x 15 www-data www-data 4096 #{timestamp} www
```

Let's review this character by character :

- `d` is for directory (`-` for a regular file, `l` for links, etc...)
- next 3 characters are the permissions for the owner of the file (`rwx` here, meaning full access `r` for reading, `w` for writing, `x` for executing)
- next 3 define permisssions for the group which the file belongs to (`r-x` means that writing is disabled)
- next 3 define permissions for any (other) user on the machine.
- The 15 is the link count (how many links to this item). It varies between platforms.
- first name (`www-data`) next is the owner of the file, for which `rwx` applies, then second `www-data` is the name of the group `/var/www` belongs to.
- Finally, you get size and name of the file.

To solve your problem of accessing `/var/www` with your user, he will have to have at least `r--` (and probably `r-x`) on the directory. This can be provided in two ways : add your user to the group that `/var/www` belongs to (use `usermod -G #{groupname} #{username}`) and make sure the group has the good rights (use `chmod` for that). Second way is to make your user the owner of `/var/www` (`chown` is your ally there).

Can you post the results of these commands in your question?

Comment: Now I've added again a new user with adduser ... But now the problems starts ... can clone my git repo in /var/www ... permision denied .... 
should I add the new user to sodoers?

Comment: this is more of a permission issue : ls -al /var | grep www will list user, group and permissions for /var/www. Are you on a development or a production environment? If on development, cloning into /var/www may be not that relevant.

Comment: this should be a test environment 

should I only do chown? or chmod? or what?

Comment: I've added a new folder inside of www and set chmod 0777 ... ... when I run bundle Install i got this error: Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.Gonna answer soon to your questions. thanks

Comment: That would be because bundler wants to install rubygems in a place your user does not have the rights to do so. Have you installed rvm as a single user? can you open a irb(pry) session and print ENV['GEM_HOME'] and ENV.select {|k, v| /rvm/i =~ k }?

Comment: irb: 


2.2.1 :001 > ENV['GEM_HOME']
 => "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1"

Comment: Ok, so this is not a single user rvm install. Any installing gem command will have to be ran as a superuser. Adding your user to the sudoers group and use sudo bundle install should do the trick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79671/discussion-between-floum-and-felix).